# Error Upgrading To .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I'm trying to upgrade from VS2010 .NET 4 to VS2012 .NET 4.5 and I'm getting the following error in each Project that I've set to .NET 4.5 when they try to build.

The expression "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToStandardLibraries(.NETFramework, ?, '', '')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long.

I can't find any references to this in my code and the msdn reference for the function doesn't provide any hints (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135279.aspx).

Anyone seen this before or know the solution?

**Edit**

The solution listed here doesn't seem to work. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vseditor/thread/8ca4a9b0-742d-487d-ab8c-6c3a80cffd40

Comment: Your existing 4.0 code should work as it is in VS2012 without retargetting projects to 4.5. If this scenario works then you are good. If you want to take advantage of new functiaonlity in 4.5, then retargetting is necessory. and then this question will be relevent. Can you confirm which path you want to take here?

Comment: I need to use new functionality only available in 4.5 unfortunately.

Comment: what kind of projects are these? mobile tools?websites?

Comment: There are class libraries and projects using WPF and WF.

Comment: Another example of the Goldilocks Dilemma: The string length can neither be too short nor too long; In effect, it must be "just right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow after multiple tries, including restarting the machine and visual studio, this started working for no apparent reason.

Comment: It is possible that Visual Studio installation required a machine restart to finish. It is possible that Visual Studio prompted restart request at the end of install but it was postponed for later. I'm glad that your project is working correctly!

Comment: That's possible, though I'm pretty sure I restarted it as part of the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Unload your project and remove the below tag from your .csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion></TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and reload your project again, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when upgrading from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 framework.
I had a big solution with many projects.
This error turned out when building the last project (win application), which had the correct `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

The cause of the problem were the other projects, used by the win app project.
They had incorrect framework versions.